Not able display the date , time and pax below the header. It is the same issue like the issue reported on top
  const newClass = {
        id: `${issuerId}.${classSuffix}`,
        classTemplateInfo: {
          cardTemplateOverride: {
            cardRowTemplateInfos: [
              {
                twoItems: {
                  startItem: {
                    firstValue: {
                      fields: [
                        {
                          fieldPath: "object.textModulesData['date']",
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                  endItem: {
                    firstValue: {
                      fields: [
                        {
                          fieldPath: "object.textModulesData['time']",
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                oneItem: {
                  item: {
                    firstValue: {
                      fields: [
                        {
                          fieldPath: "object.textModulesData['pax']",
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      };
      const newObject = {
        id: `${issuerId}.${objectSuffix}`,
        classId: `${issuerId}.${classSuffix}`,
        genericType: "GENERIC_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
        state: "ACTIVE",
        logo: {
          sourceUri: {
            uri: "https://storage.googleapis.com/wallet-lab-tools-codelab-artifacts-public/pass_google_logo.jpg",
          },
          contentDescription: {
            defaultValue: {
              language: "en-US",
              value: "LOGO_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION",
            },
          },
        },
        cardTitle: {
          defaultValue: {
            language: "en-US",
            value: "User Name",
          },
        },
        subheader: {
          defaultValue: {
            language: "en-US",
            value: "Demo demo",
          },
        },
        header: {
          defaultValue: {
            language: "en-US",
            value: "PARTY",
          },
        },
        textModulesData: [
          {
            id: "date",
            header: "DATE",
            body: "4th FEB' 24",
          },
          {
            id: "time",
            header: "TIME",
            body: "12 AM",
          },
          {
            id: "pax",
            header: "PAX",
            body: "4",
          },
        ],
        barcode: {
          type: "QR_CODE",
          value: "BARCODE_VALUE",
          alternateText: "12324334",
        },
        hexBackgroundColor: "#c01b3b",
        heroImage: {
          sourceUri: {
            uri: "https://storage.googleapis.com/wallet-lab-tools-codelab-artifacts-public/google-io-hero-demo-only.png",
          },
          contentDescription: {
            defaultValue: {
              language: "en-US",
              value: "HERO_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION",
            },
          },
        },
      };



This is what I need to achieve.

How to get this date, time and pax visible on card?
I am using the json that the pass builder has provided. but cant understand whats wrong here.
If someone is having any working code please provide the structure to help to complete the working of this pass.

cant understand whats wrong here ... you've shown some data and a picture .. .what's wrong is there's no code to create what's in the picture from the data
